# Immunity debugger not finding the process after crashing the process and detaching it

Tags: immunity-debugger

I launch both immunity debugger and vulnserver as administrator. I attach vulnserver.exe, then I send my payload to overwrite the EIP to crash it. After that I exit both immunity debugger and vulnserver and reopen them as administrator. But when I try to attach vulnserver again, it doesn't show it in the list of processes.

I can only attach it after restarting my Windows 11 OS, and then opening them as administrator(doing it all again).

Is there a way to detach the EIP overwritten vulnserver process and reattach it in immunity debugger without having to restart my computer? Because otherwise, it won't detect it in the list of attachable processes.

Comment: are you sure that the target process is still running? if yes, have you tried using other debuggers to attach to the process? (x64dbg, windbg, etc.)